# Usage of plural “layers”

Tags: plural-forms

Can “layers” be used as in “there are two layers of liquid” although two layers are totally the same?

Ex) Atmosphere consists of 4 layers because 4 layers are totally the same except temperatures.

Should there be something different?

I guess two layers are distinguished only by where they are positioned.

Ex. There are two layers. One layer is positioned at a depth from 0m to 100m, and the other layer is positioned at a depth from 100m to 200m.

Comment: Sure. There's no rule that says the substance has to change, as long as there's something different from one level to the next, you've got layers.

Comment: @gotube You mean there should be something different?

Comment: @user0070 I think It would be count to 1 layer.

Comment: If there is no difference between the layers they are not different layers!

Comment: @Kate Bunting You mean they are still layers even though they are not different?

Comment: Quite the reverse! If "two layers are totally the same", surely it is only one layer.

Comment: @Kate Bunting They should at least be different in smell or temperature to be called “two layers”? I don’t understand why gotube says “sure.”

Comment: Obviously if a substance is said to be in several layers, there must be something distinguishing the layers from one another, even if it's only temperature.

Comment: I said "sure" because user refined the question with the example about layers of temperature in the atmosphere. There are layers of water in oceans that don't interact only because their temperatures are different, so they are different layers. Kate and I are saying the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course!

You can have a [two-layer chocolate cake](http://allrecipes.co.uk/recipe/19805/two-layer-chocolate-cake.aspx), for example. Both layers are of chocolate cake.

Obviously, for the layers to be counted separately, there must be some distinguishing factor. In your example, the difference is the temperature. It could simply be that the two layers were *laid* at different times. It doesn't matter if, in the end product, the two layers are not easily distinguishable - if the process of laying them was separate, then they are different layers.